# Navmesh surface doesn't bake

Tags: unity-game-engine, navmesh

I have tried everything I could google.
my gizmo is turned on, show navmesh under ai navigation is checked, I switched to navigation
tab, navmesh surface is attached to my background. I deleted and reloaded my scene,
I don't know what else to check for. I have both checked and unchecked the navigation static box, though it shouldn't matter since I'm using 2022.3.61(newest).
I'm working on a 2d game so there's no surface raised to the 1000.
I have the same post on unity discussion but it doesn't look like I will get an answer there.
Please help me

what am I doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: looks like it did bake.....

Comment: really? how can you tell?
all the tutorial's I've seen show the blue mesh covering the walk-able area.
https://docs.unity3d.com/2022.2/Documentation/Manual/nav-BuildingNavMesh.html
It will show you obstacles and what not

Comment: the navmesh in the assets at the bottom .. are you sure you have the right gizmos turned on? and even if you cant see it, is it working?

Comment: yeah I have the navmesh surface box in gizmo checked. In fact I have everything under gizmo checked.  I attached an agent to an object and it says "failed to create agent because it is not close enough to the navMesh"